# Whay executenewLatLngBounds() function with padding has no effects on camera position padding

Tags: android, google-maps, camera, position

When the map is ready, `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` method is called, inside this method `showMapDetails(pickUp, dest)` is executed, two markers will be added to the map and the camera position is expected to fit the markers inside with padding. Unfortunately, the specified padding has no effect with the map's camera position even though the logcat shows its has the value of 100 " `Log.i("padding", padding+"");` "

```
private void showMapDetails(LatLng pickUp, LatLng dest) {
        BitmapDescriptor pickUpMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(pickUp).icon(pickUpMarker));
        BitmapDescriptor destMarker = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_end_marker);
        mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(dest).icon(destMarker));
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(createTravelCameraPosition(pickUp, dest));
    }

private CameraUpdate createTravelCameraPosition(LatLng pickUp, LatLng dest) {
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        builder.include(pickUp);
        builder.include(dest);
        builder.build();
        float dpi = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dp = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.latlng_bounds_mdpi_padding);
        int padding = (int) (dp*dpi);
        Log.i("padding", padding+"");
        return CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), padding);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#newLatLngBounds(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds, int)) description

> Do not change the camera with this camera update until the map has undergone layout (in order for this method to correctly determine the appropriate bounding box and zoom level, the map must have a size). Otherwise an IllegalStateException will be thrown. It is NOT sufficient for the map to be available (i.e. getMap() returns a non-null object); the view containing the map must have also undergone layout such that its dimensions have been determined. If you cannot be sure that this has occured, use newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int) instead and provide the dimensions of the map manually.

It suggests that you can use the overridden method to provide dimensions and padding if you're not sure if it was triggered.